# Convert Oracle database to Derby

Tags: oracle, migration, derby, tools

I need to migrate an existing Oracle Database into a Derby one. I want to know if there's a tool, a script or another way to do that work.

It is using any of the interesting features of Oracle, as I can see from the database information from SQL Developer, except sequences and indexes.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use any "interesting" features of Oracle? (Stored procedures, functional indexes, BLOB etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache DdlUtils can help with some of the migration: http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/

You might also have a skim of the tools listed here: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UsesOfDerby to see if any of those have features that help with migration

Derby also has some built-in tools for bulk-importing of data: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/rrefimportproc.html